# SQL Query taking more time to query the SQL SERVER 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008

Below is the sql query taking ~47 sec to query the SQL Server 2008 r2 Database for the first time.

but for the 2nd time it would query with in 2-3 sec. i dont know wt would be the issue. i am new to sql server. Please help me, Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SectionName) , Name, DispalyName, TypeVal 
FROM ReportData 
WHERE FileVersion = 1 
ORDER BY SectionName;
```

in the above query **ReportData** table contains 21,54,514  number of lines, but it would query only 241 number of lines becuase might be **DISTINCT**   key word.

Comment: Remove distinct keyword, use grouping or subqueries, add required indexes; if all this doesn't help, rethink database structure or query logic. Subsequent queries becoming much faster usually indicates that big amounts of data are read from hard disk first.

Answer (score 0):

The query execution plan gets cached when you run it the first time. When you run the same query a second time, therefore, it uses that plan, which removes the overhead in creating a new plan. This reduces the time to execute the query and return results.

You can read up on this on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Secondly, SQL Server provides a [Buffer Cache](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to reduce the impact caused by having to read from disk everytime. When a query is made, the read data is stored in the buffer cache. If you are running the same query, I believe that it will read from the buffer cache rather than going to disk, which would reduce the execution time considerably.

On a side note, I think 47 seconds **may** be a reasonable time given that you have more than 2 million records in the table, and your query does filtering and ordering as well. You might want to index the columns that you use for filtering or grouping.

e.g. You can create an index on `SectionName` which you specify in your `DISTINCT` clause like so:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_SectionName on ReportData(SectionName)
```

Comment: thanks for inputs, i am doing the same. if you dont mind, you can write Create Index statement for my above sql query. anyway thanks a lot for help.